# Mysql Limit Offset not working

Tags: mysql

Here is my query, which i am using for pagination

```
SELECT DISTINCT email_list.*, email_counter.phone as e_phone,email_counter.email as e_email,email_counter.marketing as e_marketing   
FROM Data_TLS_builders as email_list 
LEFT JOIN wp_pato_email_list_counters as email_counter on email_counter.email_id = email_list.URN    
LIMIT 120 OFFSET 150
```

Rather than starting at 120 and finishing at 150, which should display 30 results, mysql is returning 120 results and ignoring the OFFSET.  I have tried `LIMIT 120,150` and still the same?

Any idea how to solve?

Comment: I think you want `LIMIT 30, OFFSET 120` to show 30 results from 120th row

Comment: When using `LIMIT`, you should always have an `ORDER BY`.  Otherwise, the rows chosen are indeterminate.

Comment: Come on read the documentation https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT DISTINCT email_list.*, email_counter.phone as e_phone,email_counter.email as e_email,email_counter.marketing as e_marketing FROM Data_TLS_builders as email_list LEFT JOIN wp_pato_email_list_counters as email_counter on email_counter.email_id = email_list.URN LIMIT 30 OFFSET 120
```

`Limit` specifies number of records.

`OFFSET` specifies upto how many records it should skip.

The above query returns 30 records from 121.

Answer (score 2):

You have to switch the limit parameters.

Solution 1:

```
SELECT DISTINCT email_list.*, email_counter.phone as e_phone,email_counter.email as e_email,email_counter.marketing as e_marketing FROM Data_TLS_builders as email_list LEFT JOIN wp_pato_email_list_counters as email_counter on email_counter.email_id = email_list.URN LIMIT 30 OFFSET 120
```

Solution 2:

```
SELECT DISTINCT email_list.*, email_counter.phone as e_phone,email_counter.email as e_email,email_counter.marketing as e_marketing FROM Data_TLS_builders as email_list LEFT JOIN wp_pato_email_list_counters as email_counter on email_counter.email_id = email_list.URN LIMIT 120, 30
```

You can also have a look into the documentation: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_select_limit.asp.

Answer (score 1):

LIMIT will tell mysql HOW MANY results you want to show. 
OFFSET will tell mysql where to START.

if you want to display 30 results starting at 120, it should be:
LIMIT 30 OFFSET 120
or
LIMIT 120, 30